# Question about web site availability, where does it belong?

Tags: discussion

Here's the gist of my question. I'll add more details in my actual post. I'm not sure where it belongs.

> I have a customer that can't view my website, he get's a 404.  NSlook
>   up looks good.  How do I diagnose this problem?

Comment: When you do post the question, please don't include unnecessary apostrophes. "he **gets** a 404," not "get's"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)?

But I'd check their [FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) first and do a search for similar questions before posting.

Comment: +1, I think it's easy to forget / fail to look for dupes first on an SE site you don't normally post on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you manage the server, or is it hosted?  If you manage the server/firewalls/hosting infrastructure, then maybe serverfault, but you better also include a lot more detail in your question, unless you want an answer like 'use wireshark, and have the user try to run traceroute'.